# I want to make categories the rating of the basis of the range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, computer-science

I want to make categories the rating of the basis of the range of rating given by the user.and also I want to visualise that data.

Categories and generate the visualization of how many hotels have the rating in
the range of 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 and 4 to 5. All will follow the [ .... )
the format which means the lower limit includes and upper limit value is excluded
while generating the range.

Can any body help me..???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming ratings in the range [0, 10]. The following code plots a histogram of the ratings distribution.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# read the rating.csv file into a pandas data frame
df = pd.read_csv('rating.csv')

# rounding the feedbacks and adding them to the data frame
df['Feedback_rounded'] = df['Feedback'].apply(lambda x : math.floor(x))

# calculate the number of feedbacks for each bin
counts_per_rating = df.groupby('Feedback_rounded')['no_of_feedback'].sum()

# create a list of tuples of the form (bin, count)
ratings_with_counts = list(zip(counts_per_rating.index.tolist(),
                               counts_per_rating.tolist()))

# append tuples for bins with 0 feedbacks
for rating in np.arange(0, 10):
    if rating not in [tup[0] for tup in ratings_with_counts]:
        ratings_with_counts.append((rating, 0))

# sort the list based on the bins
ratings_with_counts_sorted = sorted(ratings_with_counts, key=lambda tup: tup[0])        

# a list of the rating bins
ratings = [tup[0] for tup in ratings_with_counts_sorted]

# a list of the corresponding counts
counts = [tup[1] for tup in ratings_with_counts_sorted]

# plot the ratings histogram
plt.bar(ratings, counts);
plt.title('Ratings Histogram');
plt.xlabel('Ratings');
plt.ylabel('Counts');
plt.xticks(ratings, np.arange(0, 10));
```

The above code, using your sample data, yields [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8SyA.jpg).

Let me know if this helps.

PS: It would have been helpful had you provided the sample data as text instead of as an image.

Comment: No bro it's not working I have to first make categories  between 0and1,1and2,2and3 like that  and those data i have to visualise.

Comment: How do you mean it is not working? Does the code run on your machine? If yes, do you mind telling me where I got your question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    dfs=pd.read_csv("rating.csv")
dfs.sort_values(["no_of_feedback"],axis=0,ascending=True,inplace=True)
category1=dfs[dfs['Feedback'].between(0,1,inclusive=True)]
category2=dfs[dfs['Feedback'].between(1,2,inclusive=True)]
category3=dfs[dfs['Feedback'].between(2,3,inclusive=True)]
category4=dfs[dfs['Feedback'].between(3,4,inclusive=True)]
category5=dfs[dfs['Feedback'].between(4,5,inclusive=True)]
count_cate_1=category1['Hotel_id'].count()
count_cate_2=category2['Hotel_id'].count()
count_cate_3=category3['Hotel_id'].count()
count_cate_4=category4['Hotel_id'].count()
count_cate_5=category5['Hotel_id'].count()
print("***************************************************")
print("                Category1               ")
print("***************************************************")
print("")
print(category1)
print("")
print("Total Hotel found in Category-1 is",count_cate_1)
print("")
print("***************************************************")


print("                Category2               ")
print("***************************************************")
print("")
print(category2)
print("")
print("Total Hotel found in Category-2 is",count_cate_2)
print("")
print("***************************************************")


print("                Category3               ")
print("***************************************************")
print("")
print(category3)
print("")
print("Total Hotel found in Category-3 is",count_cate_3)
print("")
print("***************************************************")


print("                Category4               ")
print("***************************************************")
print("")
print(category4)
print("")
print("Total Hotel found in Category-4 is",count_cate_4)
print("")
print("***************************************************")


print("                Category5               ")
print("***************************************************")
print("")
print(category5)
print("")
print("Total Hotel found in Category-5 is",count_cate_5)
print("")
print("***************************************************")

#category2.plot.bar(x='Hotel_id',y='Feedback',rot=70,title="Hotel having rating between 1 and 2")
#plt.show(block=True)

#category3.plot.bar(x='Hotel_id',y='Feedback',rot=70,title="Hotel having rating between 2 and 3")
#plt.show(block=True)

#category4.plot.bar(x='Hotel_id',y='Feedback',rot=70,title="Hotel having rating between 3 and 4")
#plt.show(block=True)

#category5.plot.bar(x='Hotel_id',y='Feedback',rot=70,title="Hotel having rating between 4 and 5")
#plt.show(block=True)

category={'Categorys':['category1','category2','category3','category4','category5'],
         'Count':[count_cate_1,count_cate_2,count_cate_3,count_cate_4,count_cate_5]}

dafa=pd.DataFrame(category,columns=['Categorys','Count'])
dafa.plot.bar(x='Categorys',y='Count',rot=70,title="Total Hotel Rating")
plt.show(block=True)
```